# What are the FirefoxProfile preferences to allow downloading jnlp content using Java Web Launcher

Tags: selenium, firefox, preferences, jnlp

I want to set Firefox preference to use "Java Web Launcher" as the default application to download jnlp content.  Same can be done through Firefox-Options-Application preferences as show in the screenshot here.

But, how can I do the using Selenium FirefoxProfile ? which preference should be modified. Any help is very much appreciated.

I have tried creating a firefox profile and looking for proper preferences to be updated

FirefoxProfile prf = new FirefoxProfile();
prf.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/jnlp");

....
??? what other properties should i set here to open jnlp using Java Web Launcher ????
....

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","....\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver ff = new FirefoxDriver(prf)

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: Added sample code i was trying to create profile and launch firefox. any help on required properties ?